# R selectively style plot axis labels

Tags: r

I currently have the following R code, and was wondering if its possible to selectively bold/italicize/apply other styles the labels on the axis

```
> w1 <- read.csv(file="test1.csv",sep=",", head=TRUE)
> w1$Commits <- w1$normal + w1$merges
> w1
        Commits normal merges
John          4      3      1
Sarah        19     13      6
Zach          3      3      0
Jacob        27     24      3
> titles <- w1$merges / w1$Commits
> titles <- sprintf("%s%%", format(round(titles * 100), 1))
> bp <- barplot(rbind(w1$normal, w1$merges), main="Playing with R", xlab="Who", names.arg=rownames(w1), col=c("blue", "red"), ylim = c(0,30))
> text(bp, rbind(w1$Commits), labels = titles, pos = 3, cex = 0.75)
```

This produces a nice barchart (I could probably have used %d instead of format but thats not important), exactly how I want it, however I also want to be able to make the names.arg list styled, so that at the bottom I can, for example see the labels:

**John** Sarah *Zach* Jacob

Is there a way to apply styles to these labels? Or some other way to mark some bars as different (gray background, etc)?

Comment: This must be dependent on the contents of "test1.csv" which remain hidden on your computer. Of course `text` will accept expressions, but we need data to work magic with.

Comment: @DWin That's why I showed the result of evaluating w1

Comment: Better would be to post output of dput(w1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bp <- barplot(rbind(w1$normal, w1$merges), 
          main="Playing with R", xlab="Who", names.arg=rep("",4), 
          col=c("blue", "red"), ylim = c(0,30))
text(bp, rbind(w1$Commits), labels = titles, pos = 3, cex = 0.75)
axis(1, at=bp, labels= parse(text= 
                     gsub("\\s", '~', paste0(c("bold(", "", "italic(", ""),  
                                             rownames(w1), 
                                             c(    ")", "",       ")", "")
                          )                 )
             )          )
```

[image]
This seems rather kludgy, but you should have seem my failed efforts at making a length 4 expression vector with `expression`, `bquote`, and `substitute`.

Comment: I needed to quote my rownames if they have spaces such that parse received `bold('John Smith')`

Comment: Use `dput(w1)` to post a data example that represents the complexity of the problem. I don't always save test objects, and in the current instance, I no longer have anything in my workspace.

Comment: I don't actually have spaces in my data, but I though I would mention it anyway in case somebody did later

Comment: Using `gsub(" ", "~"` and changing to `paste0` seemed to work.

Comment: @Dwin, I've posted an approach using `bquote`. Still pretty kludgy.

Comment: It seems to have the advantage of handling internal spaces better. Do you understand why the function body `list(x=x)` in the 'xL' construction preserves the rownames while `list(x)` does not?

Comment: @DWin is there a reason why `paste(c("bold('", "'", ...), ..., sep="")` would not work? (ie put the quotes in the paste expressions?)

Comment: Have you tried it? `"bold(X)"` is not the same as `expression(bold(X))`. But maybe I'm not understanding exactly what you meant.

Comment: `list(x=x)` is the where argument to bquote / substitute. If you make this an unnamed list, `R` will continue along the search path until it finds an object called `x`

Comment: Got it. Have never used the bquote:where argument before. Have seen earlier efforts with `sapply( ... , as.expression)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using `bquote` (and `do.call`)

```
 # the order in which you want the "bolding"
 xx <- expression(bold(.(x)), italic(.(x)), .(x), .(x))
 # a list of lists containing the information for bquote
 xL <- lapply(rownames(w1), function(x) list(x=x))
 # using Map and do.call and as.expression to create the list of expressions
 labs <- as.expression(Map(function(expr,where) {do.call(bquote, list(expr,where))},
   expr = xx, where =xL))

bp <- barplot(rbind(w1$normal, w1$merges), 
      main="Playing with R", xlab="Who", names.arg=rep("",4), 
      col=c("blue", "red"), ylim = c(0,30))
text(bp, rbind(w1$Commits), labels = titles, pos = 3, cex = 0.75)
axis(1, at=bp, labels= labs)
```

Or similarly using `substitute`

```
xs <- expression(bold(x), italic(x), x, x)
labs <- Map(function(expr,where) {do.call(substitute, list(expr,where))}, expr = xs, where =xL)
```