# expression vs call

Tags: r, expression, call

What is the difference between an expression and a call?

For instance:

```
func <- expression(2*x*y + x^2)
funcDx <- D(func, 'x')
```

Then:

```
> class(func)
[1] "expression"
> class(funcDx)
[1] "call"
```

Calling `eval` with envir list works on both of them. But Im curious what is the difference between the two class, and under what circumstances should I use expression or call.

Comment: Did you already read `?expression` and `?call`? It's a good place to start.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `expression` when you want its capacity to hold more than one expression or call. It really returns an "expression list". The usual situation for the casual user of R is in forming arguments to ploting functions where the task is forming symbolic expressions for labels. R expression-lists are lists with potentially many items, while calls never are such. It's interesting that @hadley's Advanced R Programming suggests "you'll never need to use [the `expression` function]": http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html. Parenthetically, the `bquote` function is highly useful, but has the limitation that it does not act on more than one expression at a time. I recently hacked a response to such a problem about parsing expressions and got the check, but I thought @mnel's answer was better: [R selectively style plot axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308311/r-selectively-style-plot-axis-labels/20310071#20310071)

The strategy of passing an expression to the evaluator with `eval( expr, envir= < a named environment or list>)` is essentially another route to what `function` is doing. A big difference between `expression` and `call` (the functions) is that the latter expects a character object and will evaluate it by looking for a named function in the symbol table.

When you say that processing both with the `eval` "works", you are not saying it produces the same results, right? The `D` function (call) has additional arguments that get substituted and restrict and modify the result. On the other hand evaluation of the `expression`-object substitutes the values into the symbols.

There seem to be "levels of evaluation":

```
expression(mean(1:10))
# expression(mean(1:10))
 call("mean" , (1:10))
# mean(1:10)
 eval(expression(mean(1:10)))
# [1] 5.5
 eval(call("mean" , (1:10)))
# [1] 5.5
```

One might have expected `eval(expression(mean(1:10)))` to return just the next level of returning a call object but it continues to parse the expression tree and evaluate the results. In order to get just the unevaluated function call to `mean`, I needed to insert a `quote`:

```
eval(expression(quote(mean(1:10))))
# mean(1:10)
```

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation (`?expression`):

```
...an R expression vector is a list of calls, symbols etc, for example as returned by parse.
```

Notice:

```
R> class(func[[1]])
[1] "call"
```

When given an `expression`, `D` acts on the first `call`. If `func` were simply a `call`, `D` would work the same.

```
R> func2 <- substitute(2 * x * y + x^2)
R> class(func2)
[1] "call"
R> D(func2, 'x')
2 * y + 2 * x
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes for the sake of consistency, you might need to treat both as expressions.

in this case `as.expression` comes in handy:

```r
func <- expression(2*x*y + x^2)
funcDx <- as.expression(D(func, 'x'))
> class(func)
[1] "expression"
> class(funcDx)
[1] "expression"
```